# how to delete first line in a txt file

Tags: c#

i am new in c#.

I want to delete the first line in the txt file .

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "c sharp". The language is named "C#".

Comment: You need to expand: Is copying allowed, any concurrent access?

Comment: FYI, you should really [read the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).  It will help you understand why people are downvoting your question, as well as how the site works in general.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There may be quite a few solutions for your problem if you Goggle it.

Comment: @john, wonder where all those `*.cs` files get their extension from?

Comment: @John Saunders - maybe the OP doesn't have the '#' symbol on their keyboard.

Comment: @Henk: it's clear where the "cs" extension comes from, and why the compiler is named "csc", and it's also clear that the name of the language itself is "C#". I have a suspicion that new developers who spell it "C Sharp" are learning it phonetically, perhaps because they don't have the "#" on their keyboard. And, BTW, I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically you need to copy it to another file - you can't remove (or insert) data in a file "in place". For example, in .NET 4 it's easy:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("input.txt").Skip(1);
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", lines);
```

It's *slightly* more work in older versions of .NET, at least if you want to avoid loading the whole file into memory, but still not too hard. Let me know if you need the code for an older version (and state which).

EDIT: As discussed in comments, *if* you're willing to load the whole file into memory, you can write straight back to the same file:

```
// Note that ReadAllLines is eager, not lazy like ReadLines
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Skip(1);
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);
```

Comment: You can't write "in place", but even in your example you can write back to the same file just by reopening it since you finished your read before you started your write.

Comment: its getting an error on Skip which referance i should use for skiop

Comment: @Arshiya: You add a reference to System.Core and a using directive for System.Linq.

Comment: @mydogisbox: Nope - the code I've written doesn't actually load the data until it's asked for it - it uses LINQ's deferred execution If you try giving the same filename twice it will fail.

Comment: Well, ok, maybe not in your example, but if you simply use a non-lazy read you can immediately write back to the same file.

Comment: @mydogisbox: But only if you're happy to read the whole file into memory in one go, which my code doesn't do - it can therefore handle huge files.

Comment: True, but I'm guessing the OP has no need of that and writing to the same file is what he asked for.

Comment: Thanks Its working fine . I cant vote you because i am not having 15 priveleges to vote you

Comment: @mydogisbox: I wouldn't want to make that guess, at least without making it *explicit* to start with.

Comment: @Arshiya Gm you can't upvote him but you can mark his answer as correct.

Comment: @Arshiya Gm - I wouldn't worry too much about not being able to upvote Jon Skeet as he's already got far too much Rep already :)

Answer (score 1):

```
        System.IO.StreamReader fileR = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
        string data = fileR.ReadToEnd();
        fileR.Close();
        string firstline = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf('\n') + 1);
        data = Regex.Replace(data, firstline, "");
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);
        file.Write(data);
        file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete fist line from a text file

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
string data = file.ReadToEnd();
file.Close();
data = Regex.Replace(data, "<.*\n", "");
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, false);
file.Write(data);
file.Close();
```

Comment: I was trying the above one and it did not work for some reason. So Made a Minor change to this

Comment: You can convert regular expressions from the version used in previous versions of Visual Studio to .NET Framework regular expressions by using the following table. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

can do it in one line also

```
File.WriteAllLines(origialFilePath,File.ReadAllLines(originalFilePath).Skip(1));
```

I am assuming u r giving originalFilePath as parameter to function